# sql query - how to join/union 3 tables (2 index tables and 1 data table)

Tags: mysql, join, union, multiple-tables

i got 3 tables, 2 index tables and 1 data table

tables' structure is like this:

`users`:

```
id      | name
--------+----------- 
1       | John
2       | Mike
3       | James
```

`idx` and `idx2`:

```
user_id  | user_id2 | action   | date
---------+----------+----------+----------
1        | 2        | message  | 2013-03-20
1        | 3        | message  | 2013-03-21
3        | 2        | chat     | 2013-03-21
```

earlier i had just 2 tables, 1 index table (named 'idx') and 1 data table (named 'users'), so the query was something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM idx inner join users WHERE idx.user_id='2' and idx.user_id2=users.id ORDER BY idx.date DESC
```

but now a new index table (named 'idx2') was added, the structure is similar to 'idx' (i can't combine 'idx' and 'idx2' into a single table, so we need to work with 3 tables at once)

so now i can't make a query with 3 tables

i tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM idx,idx2 inner join users WHERE (idx.user_id='2' and idx.user_id2=users.id) or (idx2.user_id='2' and idx2.user_id2=users.id) ORDER BY idx.date DESC
```

but this doesn't work, i guess the query should consist both `union` and `join`...

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your'r right UNION seems the way to go, but the table structure should match,
can you give more information? maybe using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

this should do it if i understood well your question:

```
(SELECT * FROM idx inner join users WHERE idx.user_id='2' and idx.user_id2=users.id)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM idx2 inner join users WHERE idx2.user_id='2' and idx2.user_id2=users.id) ORDER BY date DESC;
```

the query returns data from both the tables, and order them properly: check out this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e501/2) i made

Comment: nope, this doesn't work properly.
it takes all records from `idx` and then all records from `idx2`, but i need them to get mixed in one feed, sorting by `date` field

Comment: added a sqlfiddle example, so we can clarify the issue